# Arduino Mega2560 reboots after two consecutive calls to analogWrite

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega, pwm

Why does this code lead to Arduino Mega2560 constantly resetting?

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("SETUP");
  delay(500);             //without this line Serial prints "SESESESESE"
  analogWrite(10, 100);
  analogWrite(11, 50);    //reboots after this line
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("LOOP"); //doesn't reach here
}
```

Arduino serial outputs the following:

```
SETUP
SETUP
SETUP
SETUP
SETUP
SETUP
SETUP
SETUP
```

Things to note:

1) Arduino does not reboot if I substitute pins 10 and 11 with some others (8 and 9 for example), but it does also reboot with pins 12 and 13 (I guess pins 10-13 are somehow special).

2) Arduino does not reboot if I use equal values in the calls to `analogWrite` (100 and 100 for example).

Comment: Show the circuit that's wired to this.

Comment: Nothing is plugged to the Arduino, that's the intersting part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the compiler's optimizations are to blame. After adding these two lines at the start of the program it finally works as it should:

```
void setup() __attribute__((optimize("-O1")));
void loop() __attribute__((optimize("-O1")));
```

Comment: Can you please explain, why you think this is a fix?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior should not happen, if you set your pins to:

```
 void setup() {
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);  // sets the pin as output
    pinMode(11, OUTPUT);  // sets the pin as output
```

Such resets are typical of a bad power supply, noise or bad connections, (bad protoboard), or a bad LED pin (e.g.; resistor too small or damaged, or damaged pin, etc).
If your mega has no HW-defect and a sufficient power source or additional HW attached that causes this defect, it should work as expected.

Comment: why should this help.? analogWrite configures the pin

Comment: Please read the documentation carefully: In the text is written: You do not need to call pinMode() to set the pin as an output before calling analogWrite().  - So yes we should assume we do not need this. BUT in the same page example the pinmode is used and also various issues indicate that the analogWrite does not always do what it should. This Note from the documentation: NOTE: pinMode(..); is required before calling analogWrite(pin, value); or else the pin will not be initialized as a PWM output and set to the desired duty cycle. So my tip always set them explicitly to output.